# Change sms signal for specific broadcast number

Tags: sms, 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications

At work I'm on standby certain days and nights and get alarms through sms messages, I would like to give those messages another notification signal so that I know if it's an alarm or not.

They seem to be some form of broadcast messages since when I press and hold on the thread in the messaging app I only get "delete thread" and "register as spam", neither "add to contacts" or "view contact", otherwise I figured I would just add it as a contact and give that contact a specific notification signal.

I'm on a Galaxy S2 running Android 4.1.2, I haven't rooted or upgraded it except normal OTA updates.

Comment: Even if you cannot add a contact from within the messaging app, you still should be able to see the senders number and add that manually using the contacts/people app. Have you tried that?